# URL encoded category and SEO

Tags: url, seo

I have a website in russian language and categories are russian words and these words must encode like this :

%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9

What would be the best URL structure for SEO and google ?

www.example.com/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%/

or use category id  and subcategory id

www.example.com/1/4/

Comment: This is not really programming related.

Answer (score 0):

I am from Bulgaria and many Bulgarian websites use encoded URLs for their page structure. If you search Google, you will see, that many pages with encoded URIs rank on the first SERPs and Google is translating the encoded strings in their addresses to their Cyrillic alphabet analogs.

So there is no reason not use url-encoded strings in your addresses. Having a keyword in the URL is always better than having only digit IDs.